# Can't delete a row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL noob needs some help here. When I try to delete a row in a table, SQL server gives me this error:

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> No rows were deleted.
>
> A problem occurred attempting to delete row 16. Error Source: .Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider. Error Message: Cannot update or delete model.
>   Audit integrity violation.
>
> Correct the errors and attempt to delete the row again or press ESC to
>   cancel the change(s).
>
> OK  |   Help

What does it mean and how can I make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include the delete statement that you are attempting to execute?

Comment: Do you have constraints on the table?

Comment: It's a standard "delete from .... where ... " query

Comment: @Eric I expanded the tree view and don't see any constraints under the table name. Does it mean there is no constraint?

Comment: SELECT 
    TableName = t.Name,
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    dc.type,
 dc.type_desc,
 dc.name,
 dc.definition
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints dc ON t.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
where t.name = 'yourtablename'
ORDER BY t.Name

Comment: does that ^ return anything?

Comment: @Eric It doesn't return anything. When I remove the "where t.name = .." part it gives me a list of tables but none has the same name as the one I am looking at.

Comment: Instead of just saying "'s a standard 'delete from .... where ... ' query", you really should provide the actual statement you are running in your original question. Especially if you are new to SQL as you say, your "standard" query could contain something in error.

Comment: Ok, that's good, that means there are no constraints on your table. As the other people have mentioned, at this point we are going to need to see the exact syntax you used in your query